# What is a 'valid case' for bls12_381_fr?

Tags: origination, types, edo

I am trying to originate a contract using bls12_381_fr types and am running into an error. The same contract originated successfully on the `edo` branch of the [Metastate](https://gitlab.com/metastatedev/tezos.git) repository.

Now I am running the `latest-release` branch on the [Tezos](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos.git) repo but get this error when I try to originate the same contract.

```
  Invalid primitive.
  Primitive bls12_381_fr has invalid case.
```

EDIT: I am running it on sandbox mode and I ran `tezos-activate-alpha`.

EDIT: I am on hash `6102c808a21b32e732ab9bb1825761cd056f3e86` with `latest-release`. Also, [here](https://github.com/boltlabs-inc/libzkchannels/blob/master/tezos-sandbox/tests_python/zkchannels_contract/pssig.tz) is the exact contract I am trying to originate. Note that it has no storage arguments.

Comment: Can you please give more information on your setup? Which network is your node connecting to if any?

Comment: In tezos-client you can force a protocol version using the `--protocol` argument.

Comment: i just edited the question to include that it's in sandbox mode with alpha activated. Okay, I thought `edo` was active on the main release though and so I would be able to use the default protocol?

Answer (score 2):

Edo2net is not the default protocol in sandbox.

You will need to provide the `--protocol-hash` arg:

```
tezos-sandbox mini \
   --size 1 \
   --number-of-boot 2 \
   --protocol-hash PtEdo2ZkT9oKpimTah6x2embF25oss54njMuPzkJTEi5RqfdZFA \
   --no-baking \
   --until-level 2_000_000 \
   --timestamp-delay=-3600 \
```

Comment: thanks. Is there some documentation or example to follow for running `tezos-sandbox`?  So far I've been running the commands from https://tezos.gitlab.io/user/sandbox.html  e.g.   `./src/bin_node/tezos-sandboxed-node.sh 1 --connections 1`

Comment: I've also faced the same issue with the protocol recently. This documentation helped https://tezos.gitlab.io/developer/flextesa.html

Answer (score 1):

Can you give more information on your setup? Like which hash do you use?

In the latest versions of BLS12-381 (used by Edo), it has been decided to pad the bytes for Fr elements. Some users requested it because it was a bit annoying to push 32 bytes if the elements should represent 5 for instance (which can be encoded with 0x05). Previous versions of BLS12-381 used in Tezos were not padding (up to November 2020 I think), and `PUSH bls12_381_fr 0x05` was not valid. Now, `PUSH bls12_381_fr 0x05` is equivalent to `PUSH bls12_381_fr 0x05000000000000000000000000000000`) The current version of latest-release (6102c808a21b32e732ab9bb1825761cd056f3e86) does include the padding.

Comment: Also a good example by SmartPy: https://smartpy.io/ide/?template=bls12_381.py
   The test environment supports all Michelson operations.

Comment: Thanks, I added the hash and also the contract I'm trying to originate. I don't think the padding is an issue since the contract has no storage, and all I am trying to do is originate it. As Rodrigo pointed out above though, I am running sandbox using `./src/bin_node/tezos-sandboxed-node.sh 1 --connections 1`, and not specifically selecting `Edo2net`, so i think that might be the issue.